# Make a custom script modules

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, joomla, module

i want to make a script that read a folder with the files in it(modules,plugins) but i dont know how where to start,can i get from you guys examples?I want to make like wordpress or joomla plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of WordPress you are using

If you want to do that you can create a script check if there is new zip file in plugin folder , then set the script as a cronjob to check every min or 5 sec. Also you may want to check this codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook to know how to add a hook
You can check here in WordPress website wiki

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/

Follow the steps you will get it.

Comment: You do not understand(sorry for my bad english),i am making a script for my self but i want to implement a script that can read modules,plugins and install them automatically after upload a zip file or rar file

Comment: Ah I am sorry get you wrong. If you  want to do that you can create a script check if there is new zip file in plugin folder , then set the script as a cronjob to check every min or 5 sec. Also you may want to check this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook to know how to add a hook

Comment: You are welcome could you accept answer if you think it helps you? Thanks